WPF Intellisense in XAML UserControl without ViewModel
I would like to be able to use intellisense in XAML without having a ViewModel as DataContext but having the DataContext of the UserControl.cs
The goal is to be able to see properties under development.
Here is an example for demonstration purposes:
<UserControl x:Class="WpfAppNavigationViewControl.NavigationViewControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppNavigationViewControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" x:Name="PanelColumn"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Navigation Panel -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="NavigationPanel" Background="LightGray">
            <Button Content="Collapse Panel" Click="TogglePanelButton_Click"/>

            <ListView x:Name="NavigationList"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NavigationItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftIcon}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Path=RightIcon}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Main Content Area" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

Code Behind
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfAppNavigationViewControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NavigationViewControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NavigationViewControl : UserControl
    {
        private bool isPanelCollapsed = false;
        private readonly GridLength expandedWidth = new GridLength(200);
        private readonly GridLength collapsedWidth = new GridLength(50);

        public NavigationViewControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigationItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NavigationItems",
            typeof(IEnumerable<NavigationItem>), typeof(NavigationViewControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public IEnumerable<NavigationItem> NavigationItems
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable<NavigationItem>)GetValue(NavigationItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NavigationItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        private void TogglePanelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isPanelCollapsed)
            {
                PanelColumn.Width = expandedWidth;
                (sender as Button).Content = "Collapse Panel";
            }
            else
            {
                PanelColumn.Width = collapsedWidth;
                (sender as Button).Content = "Expand Panel";
            }
            isPanelCollapsed = !isPanelCollapsed;
        }
    }
}

I would like to be able to view the NavigationItems list
I expect the result like this example but it has nothing to do with the example above


Set the design-time DataContext, d:DataContext.

Can you please tell me in detail how to implement the d:DataContext...?
Because I have already made unsuccessful attempts

Please see the duplicate question.

I entered this without success
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:NavigationViewControl, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

NavigationViewControl is a control, not a view model. The design-time DataContext - as well as the standard, run-time DataContext - should of course be instances of a view model.

that's what I wanted to know, maybe it's not possible if I don't have a ViewModel.
It works with the ViewModel, I've already used it

@NewCode82 In your case, set the DataType on the DataTemplate; I expect it is  some "person" object (with "names") in the local:People collection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

@GerrySchmitz
Can you please give me an example using the code I posted previously...?

Well ... I've never found a use for a "ListBox"; I do use "ListViews" and DataTemplates extensively (which I think is what you really want). Here is a ListView example that should help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/item-templates-listview
